# not able to print properly when using select function in c

Tags: c

This is a peice of code

```
 maxfd = fileno(stdin)+1;
 FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &static_rdset);
 printf("Hello");
 select(maxfd+1, &rdset,NULL,NULL, NULL);
```

Problem is that Hello is printed only after I press enter i.e. when stdin is readable.

Comment: Please state clearly what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf()`, when STDOUT is a terminal, does line-buffering. As you have not added a linefeed after "Hello", it remains in the userspace buffer and `printf()` does not actually `write()` "Hello" to STDOUT.

Then you call `select()` which waits for user input. That achieved, your program exits, but flushes the STDOUT buffer first.

Try again with `"Hello\n"`.

Comment: Maybe you could accept the answer to show future generations how it is. :-)